# Calling setter to reset iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, getter-setter

Is there a pythonic way to reset an iterator? Here's what I thought doing but I am not sure how I would be able to reset the iterator when getting a value...

```
@property
def node_wave(self):
    try:
        wave = next(self._node_wave)
    except StopIteration:
        self._node_wave = iter(sorted(WAVELENGTH, key=lambda k: random.random()))  #call setter here to reset the iterator
        wave = next(self._node_wave)
    return wave

@node_wave.setter
def node_wave(self):
    self.node_wave = iter(sorted(WAVELENGTH, key=lambda k: random.random()))
```

Comment: This code *does* reset the iterator `self._node_wave` when getting a value. What are you confused about exactly? Please [edit] to clarify. Also, what's the actual problem you're trying to solve? Be wary of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). It'd help to make a [mre] with minimal but complete code, desired output, and undesired output.

Comment: A setter requires a value, which `node_wave.setter` is missing. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Oops the comment was hidden off-screen. So you want to call the setter on that line? I think I get what you're trying to do, like generalize the code, but using a setter makes no sense as far as I can see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than explicitly resetting `self._node_wave`, just define a private generator that takes care of cycling over the values.

```
def _wave_generator(self):
    while True:
        yield from sorted(WAVELENGTH, key=lambda k: random.random())

def __init__(self):
    self._node_wave = _wave_generator()

@property
def node_wave(self):
    return next(self._node_wave)
```

Because of how `_wave_generator` is defined, `next(self._node_wave)` will never raise `StopIteration`. When one sorted list is exhausted, another one is automatically created.